# Why i'm obligated to group by for a field in a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm working on this query, but I have  Error_code:ORA-00979 beacuse i dont want group by for a.year that i use in condition:
Any tips?
Thanks

```
select 
a.provincia_desc,
a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL,
sum(cnt) / decode(mod(to_number(a.year),4),0,1464,1460) avg
--case 
--when mod(to_number(a.year),4)=0 then sum(cnt)/1464 
--else sum(cnt)/1460 
--end avg
from
(select year ....)a
group by a.provincia_desc,a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL--, a.year
order by avg desc
```

Comment: If you don't want to group by the yaer you have to apply either MIN or MAX on it: `sum(cnt) / decode(mod(to_number(MIN(a.year)),4),0,1464,1460)`

Comment: Unrelated, but: why are you storing numbers (year) in a `varchar` column.

Comment: I want sum of cnt for all records with equival a.year

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...  The query as you wrote it doesn't make any sense. You sum a quantity `cnt` over all of subquery `a`, then you divide by a number that is either 1464 or 1460 depending on whether a "year" is a leap year or not, but the "year" is not included in the result. So imagine you have years 2001 and 2004 in your subquery `a`. In the result set you don't have a row for 2001 and another for 2004; you want everything grouped together. So what should be the denominator - 1460 or 1464?

Now, 1460 and 1464 are the numbers of six-hour periods in leap and non-leap years. I **suspect** you didn't want to divide by 1464 or 1460 (if you DON'T want the result broken down by year - if you do, then the query with `a.year` in `group by` is fine, but you said that's not what you want.) Instead, to compute the correct average you must SUM 1460 and 1464 for non-leap and leap years in your table. So, the denominator shouldn't be what you put in there; instead, it should be

```
sum(case when mod(to_number(a.year), 4) = 0 then 1464 else 1460 end)
```

so the complete expression should be

```
sum(cnt) / sum(case when mod(to_number(a.year), 4) = 0 then 1464 else 1460 end)
```

With this change you will not need to include `a.year` in `group by`, because you are in fact aggregating over all years (albeit through a complex formula).

This assumes your base data is for full years. What if your data only starts on March 23, 2001? In that case, it would be much better to compute the number of days by `max(row_date) - min(row_date)` from the base table, and then multiply by 4 to get the number of six-hour periods. This will work even better if the data starts at 9:00 AM on March 23; then you will have fractional periods.

Two more notes: Not all years divisible by 4 are leap years. You may be OK but only by luck, since 2000 was in fact a leap year and your data probably doesn't go back to 1900 or forward to 2100, but it may (or may not) be important to keep that in mind. And, you shouldn't use reserved Oracle words, like `year`, for object names or aliases. Use `yr` or other similar names.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
select 
a.provincia_desc,
a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL,
sum(cnt / decode(mod(to_number(a.year),4),0,1464,1460)) avg
--case 
--when mod(to_number(a.year),4)=0 then sum(cnt)/1464 
--else sum(cnt)/1460 
--end avg
from
(select year ....)a
group by a.provincia_desc,a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL--, a.year
order by avg desc
```

Changed the summation to include the `decode`.

Comment: This may be correct syntactically, but it makes no logical sense. What is the meaning of adding together the annual averages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to do the aggregation twice to get accurate results:

```
select a.provincia_desc, a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL,
       sum(sumcnt) / sum(numperiods) as avg
from (select a.provincia_desc, a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL,
             sum(cnt) as sumcnt,
             (case when mod(to_number(a.year), 4) = 0 then 1464 else 1460 end) as numperiods
      from (select year ....) a
      group by a.provincia_desc, a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL, a.year
     ) t
group by a.provincia_desc, a.VOLTAGE_LEVEL
order by avg desc
```

Comment: Why does this need to be done with two aggregations? You can sum over the case expression. Other than that it seems we had the same guess as to what the OP meant to do though.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Because this is the simplest way to get the number of periods per year.

Comment: I don't understand. You defined numperiods in the subquery and then summed over numperiods in the outer query. You can do both in one step - I showed how to do that in my Answer (when I wrote it I didn't realize we were doing essentially the same thing).

Comment: @mathguy . . . `numperiods` is calculated as one value per year.  I think you are missing the possibility that one year could have multiple rows.

Comment: Uh-oh.... you are absolutely right, I didn't think about that. However, judging by the little information about subquery `a` (`select year ...` and the column name `cnt` also extracted from `a`) it seems the OP had already grouped by year and counted whatever there was to be counted. But I do understand your point very clearly now, thank you!